# modify encoding for database deploy script

Tags: encoding, sql-server-data-tools, sql-scripts, database-deployment

Is there a way to change the encoding for the deploy script generated by Sql Server Data Tools from UTF-8 to ANSI?

The problem that I have is that I have a string in a function that contains the caracter "è" and in the generated deploy script a box appears instead of this character.

EDIT: I'm using SSDT with Visual studio 2013 and 2015.

Comment: I don't know anything off the top of my head, but may be worth pinging the SSDT team on Twitter to see if they have an idea - https://twitter.com/sqldatatools.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should change encoding of all files in your project to UTF-8 and deploy script will be correct.

Comment: Your answer should be some details to understand the cause.

Comment: Some time ago I have experienced a same problem and solved it as I said above.
I think this is a bug of VS, when it finds any source file with different encoding than utf-8, this fact forces it to sense all other files the same way, but VS still makes deploy script with utf-8. Changing "encoding" tag in XMLs of project files didn't give any effect.

Sorry for my short phrases, it because so difficult to write english for me.